# Couldn't click on td element

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am trying to download song from site http://www.radiojavan.com/mp3s/mp3/Aamin-Sarbaz with Ruby and Mechanize. There is a 'Download MP3' but when I inspect it it's not link but td.

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::FileSaver
download_page = agent.get('http://www.radiojavan.com/mp3s/mp3/Aamin-Sarbaz')
```

When I navigate this in browser I could click like it's link.
But in the code this is  element. How to click on this td element?

If I try:

```
download_page.search('div#download_mp3 table tr td')[1].click.save_as 'proba.mp3'
```

It raises error:
`<top (required)>': undefined method`click' for # (NoMethodError)
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't 'click' a td, partly because there's no href attribute. Because the download is handled with javascript, you won't be able to get it easily with mechanize.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion I would give is to download firerbug, then inspect the td element using the html section to a right click an copy Xpath, it will give you the something like this:

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/a[2]
```

which hopefully would be what you need.

Comment: I added `download_page.search('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]').click.save_as 'proba.mp3'` but it raises same message again. I suspect that this could be problem with Javascript.

Comment: Where do you get that xpath from? There's no such thing on that page. Also those firebug xpaths never work properly.